# Windows 10 sometimes crashes and restarts, other issues as well

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-word-2010

I have recently installed free version of Windows 10 and since then I feel my machine has many problems.  Sometimes it crashes and restarts, and so some other times mozilla Firefox stops responding, and some times Office doesn't recognise key.  Any solutions please?

Comment: Have you run a virus checker? It may not be related to win10.

Comment: If your problem is from Windows updating from a previous version and your Windows 10 has properly activated itself then one thing you can do is do a clean install from a bootable USB disk. That will have the benefit of cleaning out programs and reinstalling drivers that have not transferred cleanly. http://www.howtogeek.com/224342/how-to-clean-install-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

I had constant problems with Windows 10 when I first installed it - firefox and chrome stopped responding, crashes, restarts, issues with the mouse, etc.

These problems ALL stopped when I changed the expensive wireless Logitech keyboard and Mouse Combo (I cannot remember the modem number, sorry) for a cheap wired keyboard and mouse.  It seems there was a conflict between the logitech drivers and the new Windows 10 OS.  This is why firefox and other browsers seemed to stop responding - they were simply not receiving input from the mouse/keyboard.

It seems some 3rd party drivers have not been properly configured/updated for use with Windows 10.  Hopefully the problem driver is of a component that can be removed from the computer.

I would advise removing all peripherals from the computer, restarting and seeing if the problem remains.  If the problem disappears then you can find the offending peripheral by a process of trial and error.

Otherwise, you may need to reinstall the OS.  You can download it freely, along with the Installation Media Creation Tool from the Microsoft website - you will not need an activation code as this is stored by Microsoft, as long as you are using Genuine Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since you upgraded to Windows 10 recently, your devices’ drivers may not be compatible with new system compeletely, try update drivers from manufacturer official website, notice system version.

For your Mozilla Firefox issue, I think you can download a new installation package to reinstall it.

Also, you could collect event log to see what happened when your machine crash, go to Event Viewer to see the detail.

In fact, in-place upgrade usually leads to some trouble, I prefer to use media creation tool to install Windows 10, which can give us a clean system, check the following link for more information.

Get Windows 10

https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10

Regards